# Can't connect to Azure ADB2C tenant via PowerShell (Set-MsolPasswordPolicy command)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to connect to my Azure ADB2C tenant via powershell throungh the command `Set-MsolPasswordPolicy` (as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/set-msolpasswordpolicy?view=azureadps-1.0)).
As soon as I launch the command it tells me:

`You must call the Connect-MsolService cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets.`

1. So I run the "`Connect-MsolService`"
2. the login popup is prompted
3. I successfully login with my Azure account (which is the AAD one which is the global administrator of the ADB2C tentant as well)
4. finally I run the `Set-MsolPasswordPolicy` command
5. it asks me to `Supply values for the following parameters: DomainName:`
6. I write down the ADB2C tenant name (e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com)
7. and I get the following error:

```
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-MsolPasswordPolicy
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Set-MsolPasswordPolicy], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.RequiredPropertyNotSetException,Microsoft.Onl
   ine.Administration.Automation.SetPasswordPolicy
```

What's wrong here?
Thanks for reading and if you have any idea how to fix it please let me know.

Comment: Are you providing all 3 params? `Three settings are required, the first is the root Domain we are targeting, the second is to indicate the length of time that a password remains valid before it must be changed and the third is to indicate the number of days before the password expiration date that will trigger when users will receive their first notification that their password will soon expire.`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added the `-DomainName` the `-ValidityPeriod`, the `-NotificationDays` and finally the `-TenantId`. When I run the `Set-MsolPasswordPolicy` command. Now I get this error: `Set-MsolPasswordPolicy : Access Denied. You do not have permissions to call this cmdlet.`
Do you have any idea? Maybe I use the wrong DomainName? The one I'm using is shown under the Active Directory B2C tenant with the following format: `<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com`

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment

I tried to execute **Set-MsolPasswordPolicy** command from both global administrator account and non-global administrator account

While executing this command with non-global administrator account, I got the same error as yours

[image]

But, when I execute the same command with my global administrator account, it ran successfully

You have to be the **Global Administrator** to set MS Online password policy

Comment: Did you write your ADB2C tenantid as guid param? Thanks for your reply

Comment: Tenant ID is optional

Comment: I was able to successfully change the "PasswordPolicy" of the main Active Directory Tentant. My question is: does it effect the related ADB2C sub tenants?

Comment: are you global admin of your ad b2c tenant?

Comment: Well, the user `name.surname@organization.com` is the global administrator of the AD main tenant. But in the ADB2C tenant the user has a different and weird email which is: `name.surname_organization.com#EXT#@adb2ctenantname.onmicrosoft.com` (you know what I mean?). So probably it can't properly recognize the email? I suppose I should add the `name.surname@organization.com` as global admin into the B2C tenant?